# Field calculator to calculate if field contains certain text

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.5, if-else

I have a field (WS_Type in the screenshot) that I want to use to calculate values based on the text within the field. The number of occurrences of each WS_Type in the field is not important, but the presence of each different type in the field is. Basically, I need to create an if/then statement that says, if this field contains "NRW" AND "Diversion", then it will get a score of X. If this field contains "NRW" OR "Spring" it will get a score of Y, etc. I'm not sure how to set up this if/then statement.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create a new field for your output. Make sure it is string type.

Click Show Codeblock.

Write your code block/'Pre-Log Script Code' in python like this:

```
   def func(input):
        if 'NRW' in input and 'Diversion' in input:
            return 'X'
        elif 'NRW' in input or 'Spring' in input:
            return 'Y'
        else:
            continue
```

Then use it on the field you created like this:

new field=

```
func(!WS_Type!)
```

Comment: I would change the case, just to be sure, if 'NRW' in input.upper(). but still +1 from me.